# Nuxt.js Plugin not found: /tmp/build_fb2cdbad/plugins/heap.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import a plugin using nuxt.config.js. But it can't find the plugin when building the application. But it can find it when I just run the application using `npm run dev`. I'm using nuxt.js version: 2.14.6.
My nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default {
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: 'Trending',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/logo.jpeg' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/heap.js'
  ],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/sentry',
  ],

  sentry: {
    dsn: 'SECRET',
  },

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {},

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create heap.js in plugin folder in project directory
and in nuxt.config.js specify mode

```
plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/something.js', mode: 'server'},
  ],
```